# Minimize $\| ACE \|$ by geometrical means

Tags: geometry, optimization

I have the following figure

[image: ABC]

Where $AB=10$m, $BD=12$m and $DE=12$m. The point C can slide
along the segment BD. Now the problem is to minimize the distance from A to D 
going along the dashed line. The problem can be solved using simple analysis and differentiation. Let $BC=x$ then 
$$\|ACE\| = f(x) = \sqrt{10^2-x^2}+\sqrt{(12-x)^2+12^2}$$. in order to find a minima which we know exists one would have to solve $f'(x)=0$ to obtain the solution $x=60/11$.

My question is however can one prove without analysis that x=60/11 of $BD$ in order to minimize the distance $\|ACE\|$?

Comment: I am a little confused. You want the shortest path from A to D along the dashed line? Do you mean from A to E?

Comment: This result shows that light, whose path has equal angles of incidence and reflection, takes the shortest path when being reflected. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your math, you're minimizing $|AC|+|CE|$, not $|AC|+|CD|$.

Reflect $E$ about the line $BC$ to $E'$. Observe that $|CE| = |CE'|$, so the problem is equivalent to minimizing $|AC| + |CE'|$. Where should $C$ be? (Hint: The answer is not actually the midpoint.)

You can think of $ACE$ as a light ray reflected in the mirror $BD$. From one point of view, the solution to this problem is actually [the reason why mirrors reflect light that way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle) in the first place.

Comment: I tried to check whether this question had a duplicate before posting this answer, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: I updated my question, silly me!

Comment: @RahulNarain: I seem to remember answering a question like this before, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: @robjohn, it certainly feels like a question that must have been asked before already.

Comment: Heh, we think very much alike. Our answers are almost identical and I just added a comment about the reflection of light to the question. :-)

Comment: @robjohn: Heh. I guess this question is simple enough that the Anna Karenina principle applies: All correct answers are alike; every incorrect answer would be incorrect in its own way.

Answer (score 2):

Rahul Narain's and robjohn's answers explained details well how to solve.
I just wanted to add a picture to show the steps of the answer. Reflect E across BD to E′. The shortest $|ACE'|$ should be line. It was shown as blue line in the picture below. Others are longer as you can see.

how to find the $|BC|=x$

$\triangle ABC$ is similiar to $\triangle E'DC $

Thus 
$$\frac{10}{12}=\frac{x}{12-x}$$
$$x=\frac{60}{11}$$

[image]

Comment: I was going to add one, but got distracted. Thanks! (+1).

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks for +1 . I believe that Visual answers are always more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You must mean $|ACE|$.

Reflect $E$ across $BD$ to $E'$, then $|CE|=|CE'|$ and because a straight line is the shortest distance between two points, The shortest distance from $A$ to $C$ to $E'$ is for $C$ to be $\frac{5}{11}$ of the way from $B$ to $D$ which would make $|BC|=\frac{60}{11}$.